# Redirecting from example.com to www.example.com

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, http-redirect

My site uses AJAX, and it seems like I have to include the full path when I use it to access a function.  This is fine, as I can code it in.  The problem is, I have hardcoded http://www.example.com... but if a user has gone to http://example.com (without the www) this gives an access problem and the AJAX won't execute.

I think the easiest way to resolve this would be to make sure that if a user goes to mysite.com, they are redirected to `www.example.com`.

I can find solutions online, but they all involve the htaccess file, which my server doesn't support - I have to use rewrite.script instead.

How can I do this using rewrite.script, or is there an alternative way to approach this?

Comment: What server are you using? What is "rewrite.script"?

Comment: Interesting - this requirement looks like it is for a product called Zeus Server, but there is no even a tag for it on Stack Overflow. I suspect it is not in common usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions - I was directed to this: http://seo-website-designer.com/Zeus-Server-301-Redirect-Generator which created the rewrite.script file I needed.

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess found in your root document:

```
Redirect http://example.com/ http://www.example.com/
```

If there is no support for .htaccess on your server, you may have to include meta tag redirect on the head of your page. or using javascript to check the URL source then redirect it.

Comment: The OP said that the server does not support htaccess files.